# Prevent Apache from reverse proxying certain HTTP methods

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I am using apache as a reverse proxy to a ruby on rails application server. When a HTTP request is received with a non-standard HTTP method, this causes an error in the application server that exposes some (minor) details about the environment. Can I prevent apache from forwarding requests unless the HTTP method matches one of the safe, standard methods?

[EDIT]

Using Shane's answer as a guide, I came up with the following, posting here for reference.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|HEAD|POST|OPTIONS)
RewriteRule .* - [R=405,L]
```

I found that negating the check is easier, allows apache to return the correct response code (405 is method not allowed), and means that all of the proxy config stuff is unchanged (i.e. you can use ProxyPass or ProxyPassMatch)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be able to accomplish this with `<Limit>`:

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
  ProxyPass / http://example.com/
</Limit>
```

Edit:

Picky directives.. we'll go with plan B.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: ProxyPass cannot occur within <Limit> or <LimitExcept>

Comment: @Slicedpan Weak.  See edit for an alternative that should actually work..

Comment: Hmm gonna have to play around with it a bit, but thanks for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

If Apache reverse proxy is used, all HTTP methods can be allowed by using   directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ....com

    <Proxy "*">
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
     AllowMethods GET PUT DELETE POST
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass    ...
</VirtualHost>
```